# passing a category id to an embed

Tags: ee2, categories, embeds

I'm trying to pass a category id to an embed like so:

```
{if local_ratings=="Los Angeles"}    
{embed="embeds/ratings" cat="22"}
{/if}
```

The "local_ratings" is an EE dropdown.

In my embed I have:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="reports" disable="member_data|trackbacks"  limit="200" category="cat" dynamic="no"}     
... stuff ...
      {if absolute_count == total_results}{if:else},{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I cannot get anything to output from the embed. If I manually add an ID to the embed it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to use proper tags to access embed vars, ie:

> {exp:channel:entries channel="reports" disable="member_data|trackbacks" limit="200" category="{embed:cat}" dynamic="no"} ... stuff ... {if absolute_count == total_results}{if:else},{/if} {/exp:channel:entries}